# Forbidden: You don't have permission to access / on this server

Tags: apache

I keep having this `access denied` error. I'm using *apache 2.2.15* on *CentOs 6.4.*
The server is running with user `apache` and group `apache`.
In home, I have a user **staging**. I added him to the **apache group**.

Permissions on the docs folder are:

```
drwxrwx--- 2 staging staging 4096 Oct  4 14:33 docs
```

I'm testing with an index.html file:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 staging staging   13 Oct  4 14:28 index.html
```

*SELinux* is disabled. The address I'm using is *staging.mysite.com*

My `httpd.conf` looks like this:

```
<Directory "/home/*/docs">

#
# Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
# or any combination of:
#   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
# 
# Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
# doesn't give it to you.
# 
# The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
# http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options
# for more information.
#
    Options FollowSymLinks

# 
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
#   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#
    AllowOverride All

# 
# Controls who can get stuff from this server.
#
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

</Directory>
```

I also have a virtual host set to my staging address:

```
<VirtualHost SERVERIP:80>
        ServerName staging.mysite.com
        DocumentRoot /home/staging/docs
        ServerAdmin staging@mysite.com
        CustomLog /home/staging/logs/access_log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

If you need more info let me know but any idea why it's giving me this error?

Answer (score 1):

Well, as you stated it, the docs folder is only readable by the staging user and the staging group. So the apache user may not read it.

One solution would be to add the apache user to the staging group.

Comment: The apache user is part of the apache group and I added the staging user to the apache group like I said.

Comment: I read that, but the apache group has no read access to the docs folder.

Comment: I changed the group of /home/staging/docs and its content to apache but it did nothing...

Comment: @user2847120 And what about /, /home/ and /home/staging/? In Unix, in order to be allowed to access a file, you need read access to all parent directories.

Comment: Got it. Permissions were ok everywhere except for the folder staging. A chmod 751 did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I can fixed the same error:

To Modify at your nagios configuration the options parameter `+Indexes` and add `DirectoryIndex index.php`

**Maybe show be:**

```
<Directory "/home/*/docs">

#
# Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
# or any combination of:
#   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
# 
# Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
# doesn't give it to you.
# 
# The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
# http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options
# for more information.
#
    Options FollowSymLinks +Indexes

    DirectoryIndex index.php

# 
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
#   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#
    AllowOverride All

# 
# Controls who can get stuff from this server.
#
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

</Directory>
```

And, finally restart your apache service.

Check the permission `/home/` can be +x and +r, like `chmod +rx /home/`.

Comment: '<Directory "/home/*/docs">' syntax is not supported in Apache 2.2.15